# undo action is causing blender to crash when changing position value in a custom Panel

Tags: python, operator, panel

I'll be quick:
I created a panel.
I created a column with a prop: the position vector of a given object.

```
column = layout.column()
column.prop(MyObject, "location")
```

I can now play around the position from this custom panel.
HOWEVER: When i change the value anywhere in blender, then hit CTRL+Z, Blender crashes with an error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Here is the full code:

```
import bpy
import sys
import os
os.system('cls')


###############################################
#### Global Variables ####
AVX_cam = bpy.data.objects['AVX_Camera']

###############################################
#### Operator Classes ####

class Cam_LockView(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_options = {'UNDO'}
    bl_idname = "cam.lockview"
    bl_label = "Lock AVX Camera"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects['AVX_Camera']
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for space in area.spaces:
                    if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                        space.region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
                        space.lock_camera = True
        return {'FINISHED'}



class Cam_UnlockView(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_options = {'UNDO'}
    bl_idname = "cam.unlockview"
    bl_label = "Unlock AVX Camera"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects['AVX_Camera']
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for space in area.spaces:
                    if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                        space.region_3d.view_perspective = 'PERSP'
                        space.lock_camera = False
        return {'FINISHED'}






###############################################
#### Main Panel ####

class AVX_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """A dedicated panel for AVXcelerate Sensors"""
    bl_label = "AVX Camera"
    bl_idname = "AVX_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "AVX" 
    
    

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        
        # Lock camera to view
        layout.label(text="AVX Camera:",icon="VIEW_CAMERA")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("cam.lockview", text = 'Attach' , icon="LOCKED")
        row.operator("cam.unlockview", text = 'Detach' , icon="UNLOCKED")
               

        # Position and Orientation
        column = layout.column()
        
        column.prop(AVX_cam, "location")
        print(column.prop)
        


###############################################
#### Class (Un)Registration ####
def register():
    
    bpy.utils.register_class(Cam_LockView)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Cam_UnlockView)    
    bpy.utils.register_class(AVX_Panel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Cam_LockView)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Cam_UnlockView)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AVX_Panel)
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    #subscribe_to_all_rns()
```

It's driving me crazy not knowing how to fix this issue.

Comment: You are using `bpy.context` in your `execute` functions.  You should use the context argument that was passed in instead, so replace `bpy.context` with `context` everywhere.

Comment: @Gorgious how can i set this up in an internal Blender operator? I know i can set this for custom operators, but in my case I'm simply including the location of my object in the panel by using:
layout.row().prop(MyObject, "location")

How can i pass on this argument in the row().prop method?